# What is the range and domain of the following function

Tags: calculus, functions

I have the function $f(x,y)=\arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{\sin(x+y)}\right)$

I understand that for the domain, $\sin(x+y)$$\neq0$ and therefore $x+y\neq n \pi$

Also what is the range of the function?

Comment: another thing to be noted is that $ -1>=(1/sin(x+y)) and (1/sin(x+y))>=1 $ which implies that $(\pi/2)>arctan(1/sin(x+y))>=(\pi/4) and  (-\pi/4)=<arctan(1/sin(x+y))<(-\pi/2) $

Answer (score 1):

Let's say,$x+y=t$,so that $f=\arctan(1/sint)$.

Now ,$-1\le sint\le 1 \implies 1/sint \ge 1 $ or $\le -1$.

$arctan()$ is an increasing function so 
$f=\arctan(1/sint)\ge \arctan(1)$or $\le \arctan(-1)\implies f\ge \pi/4 $ or $f\le -\pi/4$

Assuming that,you are actually working with principal branch of tan inverse function (that is $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$),range of $f$ is $(-\pi/2,-\pi/4]\cup [\pi/4,\pi/2) $

Comment: thank you very much. for the domain, is it enough to say that x$\neq n\pi$ , y$\neq n\pi$ for n in the integers?

Comment: According to me it should be enough as arctan can operate on all real values.

Comment: @LaurenBathers: No,It's not.Take the point $(\pi/2,3\pi/2)$ for example.It's not in domain(f).(Is it?)But can you get  it from "dom(f) is$x\neq n\pi,y\neq n\pi"$? Absolutely No.